# Two Python modes

Tags: python

I have been trying to configure Emacs to use the proper Python mode. To this end I have read a few tutorials. Most importantly [this one](http://www.jesshamrick.com/2012/09/18/emacs-as-a-python-ide/). The tutorial uses the `python-mode` package. However, when I install it through the package manager (`M-x package-install RET python-mode RET`) I can not use the shortcuts that are available for that package.

I opened up a Python file to test [some shortcuts](http://python.about.com/b/2007/09/24/emacs-tips-for-python-programmers.htm) such as `C-c |`, which should evaluate the selected expression. However, to my surprise these did not work so I decided to find out other tutorials on the topic. However, in my mode-line I do see `Python`, so there is some `python-mode` enabled.

On the emacs wiki I found the following snippet to add to my `init.el` file:

```
 (autoload 'python-mode "python-mode" "Python Mode." t)
 (add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.py\\'" . python-mode))
 (add-to-list 'interpreter-mode-alist '("python" . python-mode))
```

When I add this the `python-mode` actually works and the aforementioned shortcuts work as well.

I do not understand properly what this does more than manually executing `M-x python-mode` in a python file buffer.

When I removed every trace of `python-mode` in my .emacs folder and opened up a python file I noticed that I still have a `python-mode`. So my guess is that there are two `python-mode`s?

I think I want the `python-mode` from https://launchpad.net/python-mode. It seems that it is present in the package repository, but I am unsure how to remove the other Python mode.

Could somebody elaborate please?

Comment: If you want to use Ipython, [ein](https://github.com/millejoh/emacs-ipython-notebook) is an excellent package. It gives you the equivalent of Ipython notebook in Emacs. [Demos here](https://github.com/millejoh/emacs-ipython-notebook/wiki/Screenshots).There are also [old demos](https://github.com/tkf/emacs-ipython-notebook/wiki/Screenshots) from the original repo now unmaintained.

Comment: That's a whole lotta text for a pretty simple question. ;-) Would be nice to trim it down a bit.

Comment: I agree.  I was being thorough as other SE sites have thought me.  I will trim it a bit asap.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Well yes there are two python modes: the one which ships with emacs is `python.el` and the other one is `python-mode.el` which is indeed this one: https://launchpad.net/python-mode

Your tutorial has been referencing the later one.

Your `python-mode` setup snippet does the following:

```
;; by default, the function 'python-mode is associated with
;; the package python.el. The following changes that to python-mode.el:
(autoload 'python-mode "python-mode" "Python Mode." t)

;; open py files with python-mode
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.py\\'" . python-mode))

;; sets python interpreter mode to be python-mode
(add-to-list 'interpreter-mode-alist '("python" . python-mode))
```

Comment: So do I remove python.el or do I have to combine them?   Or is there a specific name for the latter python mode? I want my `init.el` to be portable so removing `python.el` might not be an option.

Comment: Just install python-mode.el and set it up with the snippet you posted. (or read its README)

Comment: I understand what the command does, in combination with this answer: http://superuser.com/questions/108233/how-can-i-prevent-the-python-el-that-ships-with-emacs-23-from-ever-loading Thank you for elaborating.

Answer (score 8):

As a maintainer of python-mode.el and in addition to answer by @Adobe: python-mode.el does not unload commands from python.el - both are available. Due to name of python-mode-map --which is used by both and can't be changed without breaking a lot of things-- keybindings and menu are delivered from the last one loaded.

<kbd>C-c |</kbd> calls `py-execute-region` and works nicely here.
Maybe python.el was loaded afterwards and the binding gone. Calling the command via M-x might be an option than. In case of trouble, please consider a bug-report at https://bugs.launchpad.net/python-mode

Answer (score 1):

Despite some people using this package, and despite the fact that it seems to be the first Python supporting library for Emacs, I recommended to the author to rename the feature of this library, maybe to something like 'py-mode'.

As it stand, as soon as you download the python-mode.el file and it sits inside your ~/.emacs.d/elpa directory it will be used by Emacs over the python.el that is now packaged with Emacs.

The confusion comes from the clash of these 2 files:

- The python.el file that is packaged with Emacs provide the feature 'python-mode and the major mode command 'python-mode.
- The python-mode.el file you can get from MELPA provides the same 'python-mode feature and major mode.

I wish this situation would not be allowed by package managers and since python.el is now distributed with Emacs I think the authors of python-mode should rename, at the minimum, their feature and probably their file.